# Artifactory deploy issue - unauthorized

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory

I am deploying artifacts to jfrog Artifactory in cloud which is throwing unauthorized for few artifact deploy but not for others.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Also, I would like to check if there is a way to restore initial Artifactory user permissions as I made some changes with permissions and now I do not see many options (not able to create users, groups,repositories, couldn't see default repositories) which were there initially.

Can someone advice how to restore default settings for this user?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the answers to your questions.

1. > *I am deploying artifacts to jfrog artifactory in cloud which is throwing unauthorized for few artifact deploy but not for others.*
   >
   > *Did anyone face similar issue?*

   **Answer**: Its wired, if a user is having permissions to the particular repository to deploy, then the same user can deploy any artifacts to the repository until and unless an include/exclude pattern is set at the repository level.

   Further details can be found [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-CommonSettings).
2. > *I would like to check if there is a way to restore initial artifactory user permissions as I made some changes with permissions and now I do not see many options(not able to create users, groups,repositories,couldnt see default repositories) which were there initially.*
   >
   > *Can someone advice how to restore default settings for this user?*

   **Answer**: As its a cloud instance, so we will not have any control over restoring the users permission to previous state. If it was a on-prem instance then it could be achieved by restoring from the backup. You can reach out to JFrog Support cloud team and check if they can help you with it.
   If you remember the previous permissions the user then you can login with the admin user and set it, Else the other option is to create a new user with required permissions.